# javascript html form validation with array

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Sorry if my title is confusing, I do not know how to accurately describe the array I am using.
I am using simple ajax so that the user can select the number of providers on the case. This then populates the correct number of drop down boxes.
Basically the drop downs are created with this php/html code where q is the number of providers chosen by the user:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=(intval($q)); $i++)
{
    echo "Name of Anesthesia Provider " . $i . ": ";
    echo "<select name=\"anesthesiaprovider[]\">";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Anesthesia_Provider ORDER BY Lname");
    if (!(mysqli_query($con, $sql))) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Error in inserting data: ' . mysqli_error($con);
    }

    echo "<option name=\"anesthesiaprovider[]\" value=\"selectprovider\">Anesthesia Provider " . $i . "</option>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option name=\"reviewer\" value=\"" . $row['Anesthesia_Provider_Number'] . "\">" . $row['Lname'] . ", " . $row['Fname'] . "</option>";
    }   
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I want to use javascript to make sure that for each box a provider is chosen. If one isn't chosen, to highlight it in yellow. This is my javascript code, it validates the form onsubmit:

```
function validateQualityReport(theForm)
{
    var reason = "";
    reason += validateCase(theForm.case);
    reason += validateAnesthesiologists(theForm.element['anesthesiaprovider[]'])

    if (reason != "") {
        alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
        return false;
    }
    alert("All fields are filled correctly");
    return false;
}

function validateAnesthesiologists(fld){
    var error = "";
    alert(fld.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < fld.length; i++) {
        if (fld[i].value =="selectprovider"){
            fld[i].style.background = 'Yellow';
            error += "Make a selection for provider " + (i+1).toString() + "\n";
        }else{
            fld[i].style.background = 'White';
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

The code works for everything other than when one provider is chosen. Then it says that fld.length is 56 (so everything in the dropdown box), and when it highlights, it doesn't highlight the whole dropdown it highlights only the first one. What is going on here? 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing, but as far as I can tell, the only the first element is being "highlighted" as yellow because you are specifically filtering for it:
    `if (fld[i].value =="selectprovider"){ fld[i].style.background = 'Yellow';`

If you change the else statement from
    `fld[i].style.background = 'White';`
to
    `fld[i].style.background = 'Yellow';`
The remaining elements in the list will also be "highlighted".

For what its worth I would personally also change your loop of the children of that select to be more explicit, by using `node.children.length` and `node.children[i]`

Comment: fld[i] should be each individual selection, so if the user wanted to input 4 providers then i would iterate from 0 to 3. So fld[0] should be the first provider choice, not the first choice in the drop down. Also, since I am passing in the array so that fld = theForm.elements['anesthesiaprovider[]'], so I think it covers what you are saying about being more explicit, correct me if I am wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code needs the following changes

```
// move sql query out of loop as don't need to read 'q' times
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Anesthesia_Provider ORDER BY Lname");
if (!(mysqli_query($con, $sql))) {
    echo '<br>Error in inserting data: ' . mysqli_error($con);
} else {

for ($i=1; $i<=(intval($q)); $i++)
{
    echo "Name of Anesthesia Provider " . $i . ": ";
    echo "<select name=\"anesthesiaprovider[]\">";

    // remove name attribute as invalid HTML
    echo "<option value=\"selectprovider\">Anesthesia Provider " . $i . "</option>";
    // move to start of result - untested but should work
    $result->data_seek(0);
    // loop through results
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row['Anesthesia_Provider_Number'] . "\">" . $row['Lname'] . ", " . $row['Fname'] . "</option>";
    }   
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}}
```

Your JavaScript code should now only find the anesthesiaprovider[] that is associated to each <select> element and not the <option> elements. This is the reason why the highlighting was incorrect.

I am not sure why you are getting the number 56 if only one listbox is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for these tips, I changed my code to reflect this. It still doesn't solve my issue with the boxes though. I am still working through it.